# Python/Tweepy retweet following twitter accounts

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to create a twitter bot using tweepy/python to use as a filter account, to retweet relevant tweets.

I am able to search for tweets that contain a certain word/# etc but was wondering if there is code to enable the account (of which the app is registered with) to retweet all tweets of the accounts it is following.

Please find attached code underneath.

```
user = api.me()
print(user.name)

def main():
    search = ("example1")
     
    numberofTweets = 5
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberofTweets):
        try:
            tweet.retweet()
            print("Tweet Retweeted")
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
        except StopIteration:
            break
main()

def main2():
    search = ("example2")
     
    numberofTweets = 5
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, search).items(numberofTweets):
        try:
            tweet.retweet()
            print("Tweet Retweeted")
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print(e.reason)
        except StopIteration:
            break
main2()

while True:
    time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: Without looking too much into things, it looks your `search` variables are intended to be tuples? If that's the case, you need to insert a trailing comma.

Comment: Note that automated retweets are against the Twitter automation rules you agreed to when signing up for the developer account, and can lead to your account, app and IP being banned. You may want to rethink what you are building. https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation

Answer (score 0):

```
api.update_status("@" + username + " " + certain_word, in_reply_to_status_id = tweetId)
```

You can take a look at [this tutorial](https://python-catalin.blogspot.com/2019/05/use-tweepy-to-deal-with-twitter-api.html).